# ios - Personal sprite for each UIButton or one sprite + UILabel?

Tags: ios, graphics, resources

Tittle is pretty much the question, what would be better : 
create one kind of button and add UILabel with custom font to it or just create each button in photoshop and add as image assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As time passes I found out that creating a single sprite + UILabel is much more flexible and useful, brings a lot more possibilities.

Also, if you, for example, have to have different sprites for UIButton's states (disabled, highlighted etc) it would be a big pain to create N * 4 sprites.